# Django - what is the difference between render(), render_to_response() and direct_to_template()?

Tags: python, django

Whats the difference (in language a python/django noob can understand) in a view between `render()`, `render_to_response()` and `direct_to_template()`?

e.g. from [Nathan Borror's basic apps examples](https://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps)

```
def comment_edit(request, object_id, template_name='comments/edit.html'):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=object_id, user=request.user)
    # ...
    return render(request, template_name, {
        'form': form,
        'comment': comment,
    })
```

But I've also seen

```
    return render_to_response(template_name, my_data_dictionary,
              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And

```
    return direct_to_template(request, template_name, my_data_dictionary)
```

Whats the difference, what to use in any particular situation?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

```
render(request, template[, dictionary][, context_instance][, content_type][, status][, current_app])
```

`render()` is a brand spanking new shortcut for `render_to_response` in 1.3 that will automatically use `RequestContext` that I will most definitely be using from now on.

---

2020 EDIT: It should be noted that `render_to_response()` was removed in Django 3.0

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response

```
render_to_response(template[, dictionary][, context_instance][, mimetype])¶
```

`render_to_response` is your standard render function used in the tutorials and such. To use `RequestContext` you'd have to specify `context_instance=RequestContext(request)`

---

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template

`direct_to_template` is a generic view that I use in my views (as opposed to in my urls) because like the new `render()` function, it automatically uses `RequestContext` and all its `context_processor`s.

But `direct_to_template` *should be avoided* as function based generic views are deprecated. Either use `render` or an actual class, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/generic-views-migration/

I'm happy I haven't typed `RequestContext` in a long, long time.

Comment: Correction. According to docs `render()` is available from 1.3.

Comment: @AppleGrew, nice catch! The "Community" modified my post to point to specific branches and they picked 1.4

Comment: Do note: function based **generic views** are deprecated, not function based **views**. Generic views that ship with Django are now implemented using class based views (TemplateView), they used to be implemented as functions (direct_to_template, etc). Views implemented as functions, my personal preference, are still supported and that won't change.

Answer (score 42):

Rephrasing Yuri, Fábio, and Frosts answers for the Django noob (i.e. me) - almost certainly a simplification, but a good starting point?

- `render_to_response()` is the "original", but requires you putting `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` in nearly all the time, a PITA.
- `direct_to_template()` is designed to be used just in urls.py without a view defined in views.py but it [can be used in views.py to avoid having to type RequestContext](https://web.archive.org/web/20130527012805/http://www.import-awesome.com/youre-using-rendertoresponse-psh-heres-direct)
- `render()` is a shortcut for `render_to_response()` that automatically supplies `context_instance=Request`....
  Its available in the django development version (1.2.1) but many have created their own shortcuts such as [this one](http://fi.am/entry/shortcutting-render_to_response/), [this one](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/133/) or the one that threw me initially, Nathans [basic.tools.shortcuts.py](https://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps/blob/master/basic/tools/shortcuts.py)

Comment: The first link (http://www.import-awesome.com/youre-using-rendertoresponse-psh-heres-direct) is giving 404

Comment: Yeah, that can happen on links that are almost 4 years old!

Answer (score 26):

Render is

```
def render(request, *args, **kwargs):
    """ Simple wrapper for render_to_response. """
    kwargs['context_instance'] = RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response(*args, **kwargs)
```

So there is really no difference between `render_to_response` except it wraps your context making the template pre-processors work.

Direct to template is a [generic view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template).

There is really no sense in using it here because there is overhead over `render_to_response` in the form of view function.

Answer (score 12):

From django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/shortcuts/#render):

> render() is the same as a call to
>   render_to_response() with a
>   context_instance argument that that
>   forces the use of a RequestContext.

`direct_to_template` is something different. It's a generic view that uses a data dictionary to render the html without the need of the views.py, you use it in urls.py. Docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template)

Answer (score 6):

Just one note I could not find in the answers above. In this code:

```
context_instance = RequestContext(request)
return render_to_response(template_name, user_context, context_instance)
```

What the third parameter `context_instance` actually does? Being [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext) it sets up some basic context which is then added to `user_context`. So the template gets this extended context. What variables are added is given by `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in settings.py. For instance django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth adds variable `user` and variable `perm` which are then accessible in the template.