# CSRF Token missing or incorrect

Tags: python, django, django-forms, csrf

Beginner at Django here, I've been trying to fix this for a long time now.
I do have 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' in my middleware classes and I do have the token in my post form.

Heres my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from chartsey.authentication.forms import RegistrationForm
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

def register(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        c = RequestContext(request.POST, {})
        form = RegistrationForm(c)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

    return render_to_response("register.html",  {'form': form,  }, )
```

Here's my Template:

```
{% block content %}

    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: CSRF token missing or incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321217/django-csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect)

Comment: This article solved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20895547/14690597

Comment: This article solved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20895547/14690597

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## Update: This answer is from 2011. CSRF is easy today.

These days you should be using the `render` shortcut function `return render(request, 'template.html')` which uses `RequestContext` automatically so the advice below is outdated by 8 years.

1. Use `render` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/
2. Add CSRF middleware https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/
3. Use the `{% csrf_token %}` template tag
4. Confirm you see the CSRF token value being generated, AND submitted in your form request

## Original Response

My guess is that you have the tag in the template but it's not rendering anything (or did you mean you confirmed in the actual HTML that a CSRF token is being generated?)

Either use `RequestContext` instead of a dictionary

```
render_to_response("foo.html", RequestContext(request, {}))
```

Or make sure you have `django.core.context_processors.csrf` in your `CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

[Or add the token to your context manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/)

Comment: That did it! I'm still having a little trouble fully understanding it, but at least I'm past staring blankly and trying to randomly change things. The docs didn't help me too much, thanks so much!

Comment: This is step 3 in the docs :) Django's docs are amazing if you let yourself dig in a little bit. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my problem. General advice for everyone: check if you user render_to_response() with the proper parameters, I messed up and given it 3 parameters, therefore it resulted in the above error.

Answer (score 6):

Just add this to your views

`return render_to_response("register.html",  {'form': form,  }, context_instance = RequestContext(request))`

It will work!!

Answer (score 4):

Try using **render** instead of **render_to_response**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

render(request, "foo.html", {})
```

[Django - what is the difference between render(), render_to_response() and direct_to_template()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154358/django-what-is-the-difference-between-render-render-to-response-and-direc)

As stated in the link above it was introduced in Django 1.3 and automatically uses **RequestContext**

Answer (score 1):

for Django version 3.0 add the below annotation

```py
@csrf_protect
def yourfunc(request):
    return render(request, '../your.html', None)
```

And don't forget add the below tag in your field

```html
<form action="add/" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.

Answer (score 0):

The addition of `RequestContext` is the key when using `render_to_response` as mentioned by @Yuji 'Tomita' Tomita and @Njogu Mbau. However, what initially threw me off when I was struggling with this problem was that I had to add `RequestContext` to both the function in `views.py` that initially loads the template and to the function in `views.py` that handles the submission from the template.

Also, just for reference, here are some other links that discuss this same problem

- [Django - CSRF token missing or incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050991/django-csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect)
- [Django 403 CSRF token missing or incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221980/django-403-csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect)
- [Django --CSRF token missing or incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731305/django-csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect)
- [Django CSRF Cookie Not Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716624/django-csrf-cookie-not-set) *

Answer (score 0):

Also got this error randomly on some pages after I installed django-livereload-server. Uninstalling django-livereload-server did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, but honestly, I hit refresh on my browser a few minutes later without changing anything and it worked that time. I had this message in my command line as so it might provide a clue as to what was causing the issue:

```
Not Found: /css/reset/reset.css
[03/Jul/2020 20:52:13] "GET /css/reset/reset.css HTTP/......
```

Answer (score 0):

#### DJANGO/AJAX WORKFLOW FULL METHOD IS HERE :)

```
const url = "{% url 'YOUR_URL_NAME' pk=12345 %}".replace(/12345/, id.toString());
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {'id':id, "csrfmiddlewaretoken": '{{csrf_token}}'},
        beforeSend: function() { $('#response').text('Please wait ...'); },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response)           
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        }
    })
```

**Hope It Will Work !!!**

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was commenting out the below line from my `settings.py`

`'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'`

Comment: This just removes CSRF protection entirely; it doesn't address the actual problem.