# Django: CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: python, django, django-views

The error is at location http://127.0.0.1:8000/fileupload/form.py

I have version 1.3 of django. I have tried specifying localhost:8000 as stated in someone else's question but this did not work for me.  I am trying to have a file upload form but I am receiving an error that form.py does not have the CSRF token.

form.py:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):

    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file  = forms.FileField()
```

views.py:

```
def upload_file(request):

    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))

    if (not request.user.is_authenticated()) or (request.user == None):
      return HttpResponseRedirect("/?error=11")


    if request.method == 'POST':
      form = c['UploadFileForm'] = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES,  c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

      if c['UploadFileForm'].is_valid():
        handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')

    else:
        form = c['UploadFileForm'] = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('fileupload/upload.html', {'form': c['UploadFileForm']})
```

upload.html:

```
{% block main_content %}


  <form action="fileupload/form.py" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>

      <tr><td>Title:</td><td><input type="text" name="title" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td>File:</td><td><input type="file" name="file" /></td></tr>
    </table>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class = "float_right button_input" />

  </form> 

{% endblock main_content %}
```

I am very stumped please tell me some things to try. Thank You

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to pass `RequestContext` in render_to_response for `csrf_token`

For this :  (**views.py**)

```
from django.template import RequestContext

...

return render_to_response('fileupload/upload.html', {'form': c['UploadFileForm']},  RequestContext(request))
# Added RequestContext
```

This passes the token for csrf to the template.

Comment: You have already used `{% csrf_token %}` in your template, so this should work.

Comment: with the addition of the RequestContext I am getting a type error __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context_instance'

Comment: Thank You, I just figured it out. It was adding RequestContext(request) like you said and removing c and context_instance= from the if statement. If you change your answer to include that I will mark it correct.

Comment: Accepting the answer by clicking the tick helps on stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 5):

It can also happen if you use `@cache_page(60 * 15)` decorators. If you cache a page with a form containing a CSRF token, you'll cache the CSRF token of the first user only. So it's kinda hard to debug sometimes.

More info from [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#caching)

> If the **csrf_token** template tag is used by a template (or the **get_token**
>   function is called some other way), **CsrfViewMiddleware** will add a
>   cookie and a **Vary: Cookie** header to the response. This means that the
>   middleware will play well with the cache middleware if it is used as
>   instructed (**UpdateCacheMiddleware** goes before all other middleware).
>
> However, if you use cache decorators on individual views, the CSRF
>   middleware will not yet have been able to set the Vary header or the
>   CSRF cookie, and the response will be cached without either one. In
>   this case, on any views that will require a CSRF token to be inserted
>   you should use the **django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_protect()**
>   decorator first:
>
> ```
> from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
> from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
>
> @cache_page(60 * 15)
> @csrf_protect
> def my_view(request):
>     ...
> ```

Answer (score 2):

My answer is similar to the @Yugal Jindle's answer above.

I am using Django 1.10 and I had a similar issue, it worked for me after editing

```
return render_to_response(param1, param2)
```

to

```
return render(request, param1, param2)
```

P.S. Make sure you have the below line in your MIDDLEWARE variable in the settings.py

```
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'
```

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I use AJAX to post data to my views function, then the same error happens, so the easy method to solve it is to change the data from

```
data:{ 'k':'v' }
```

To

```
data:{ 'k':'v' ,addcsrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}',}
```

because we manually add a csrf-token, so it is not missing or incorrect.