# Django csrf token missing or incorrect error

Tags: django, csrf, django-csrf

I have been developing a site using Django and am trying to implement a simple form, based off of one of the models inside my app. I have a few issues with getting it to work, but my current major problem is that I keep receiving the following error:  CSRF token missing or incorrect.

I am running Django 1.6 with python 2.7.

I have already looked over the following posts to try fix my problem (and various other solutions to which I give contextual reference to where appropriate), but it has not worked for me:

[Django: CSRF token missing or incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321217/django-csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect) - Basically, passing `RequestContext` along with my `render_to_response` return.

[CSRF Token missing or incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089224/csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect) - I have made sure that `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` appears in my `settings.py` file and I have tried to add the `django.core.context_processors.csrf` as instructed to my TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting but there is no change. When I check these settings in the shell, I get the following output:

```
> from django.conf import settings
> settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
('django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
'django.core.context_processors.debug', 'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
'django.core.context_processors.media', 'django.core.context_processors.static',
'django.core.context_processors.tz',
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages')
```

I placed the following code in my settings.py file but I continue to get the 403 CSRF token error:

```
import django.conf.global_settings as DEFAULT_SETTINGS

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = DEFAULT_SETTINGS.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    'django.core.context_processors.csrf',
)
```

I have also followed the suggestions given in the error message itself, i.e. makign sure I have the {% csrf_token %} tags in place, using RequestContext instead of Context.

from my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect, csrf_exempt
from django.template import loader, Context
from django.http import HttpResponse
from forms import StudentForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.template import RequestContext

def edit(request):
form = StudentForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return Redirect('/myprofile/')
return render(request, 'myprofile.html',{'form':form})
```

Please not that I have read several other guides to fixing this problem that involve including RequestContext in several different ways: `return render_to_response('myprofile.html', RequestContext(request, {}))` and `return render_to_response('myprofile.html', RequestContext(request))`, none of which worked for me.

my settings.py file:

```
import django.conf.global_settings as DEFAULT_SETTINGS

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myprofile',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)


TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = DEFAULT_SETTINGS.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    'django.core.context_processors.csrf',
)
```

My html code is as follows:

```
<form action = "/myprofile/" method = "post"> {% csrf_token %}
  <ul>
  {{ form.as_ul }}
  </ul>

  <input type = "submit" name = "Submit" value = "Edit Form">
</form>
```

Please not that I have also attempted to add the token as a hidden input, but this has not solved my issue. The function that generates this view is also the same function that is referred to by the form's action, `<form action = "/myprofile/" ...>`.

Any assistance with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
return render_to_response('myprofile.html',{},RequestContext(request))
```

Although you have added the csrf:

```
c = {}
c.update(csrf(request))
```

You don't do anything with `c`.  To solve this once and for all, just use the [`render` shortcut](http://django.me/render):

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def edit(request):
     form = StudentForm(request.POST or None)
     if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/myprofile/')
     return render(request, 'myprofile.html', {'form': form})
```

Next, in your template, you only use `{% csrf_token %}` not both it and `{{ csrf_token }}`. The tag will render the form field.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've followed your suggestions but am still receiving the same error. This leads me to believe that this issue might be arising from a different aspect of my code, rather than just the raw code inside the files.

Answer (score 2):

*{{ csrf_token }}* seems to be empty and overrides the hidden input field which is generated by *{% csrf_token %}*. just remove the hidden input field with *{{ csrf_token }}* from your template and it should work probably.

Also, as you are using *RequestContext* you don't have to add the CSRF token manually to the template, so you can remove following code from your view.

```
c = {}
c.update(csrf(request))
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-csrf-works for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I commented on Khalid's answer, only because his covered the same idea and more. Your link did provide me with some very useful added information I had missed, but hasn't quite solved my issue.