# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted when updating a form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have the following template

```
{% block content %}
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Which is build up using this model

```
class TProfiles(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'profiles'

class TProfilesForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TProfiles
        fields = ['first_name', 'surname', 'email']
```

Which get passed to the view

```
def register(request):
    form = TProfilesForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TProfilesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    return render_to_response("register.html", {
        "form": form,
    })
```

However, I keep getting errors when trying to save the fields. CSRF errors seem to come in many flavours...

**EDIT - Error message**

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Help
Reason given for failure:
    CSRF token missing or incorrect.

In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django's   CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:
Your browser is accepting cookies.
The view function uses RequestContext for the template, instead of Context.
In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.
If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.
You're seeing the help section of this page because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and only the initial error message will be displayed.
You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.
```

Comment: Can you post traceback?

Comment: They may indeed come in many flavours, but yours is *explicitly* addressed by the error message you saw (but did not post) when you tried this; you are not using a RequestContext.

Comment: Apologies, please see my edit. This is everything on the error page that I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or Simply Use render instead of render_to_response:

```
return render(request,"register.html", {"form": form,})
```

With import :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be to add `RequestContext(request)` to the return statement. So my code looks like:

```
def register(request):
    form = TProfilesForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TProfilesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()


    return render_to_response("register.html", {
        "form": form,
    }, RequestContext(request))
```

The answer was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8321270/1213864)