# csrf token missing in django

Tags: django, csrf

I have a problem about django csrf. Here is my view code.

```
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
      res = {"is_authenticated": "true"}
    else:
      res = {}

    return render_to_response('app/index.html', res, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Can you be more precise where are you getting error? Normally it comes when you are missing `csrf_token` tag in your form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: CSRF token missing or incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321217/django-csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `CsrfViewMiddleware` is added in your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` tuple in `settings.py` and then you can simply do `{% csrf_token %}` inside the template to get the token.

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    ...
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    ...
    ...
)
```

**app/index.html**

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```

Refer [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/) for more info.

Answer (score -2):

In your views.py use @csrf_exempt decorator above your function, for that need to import this decorator first like this

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
```

then use it in your view function for eg.

```
@csrf_exempt
def sample_func(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        res = {"is_authenticated": "true"}
    else:
        res = {}
    return render_to_response('app/index.html', res, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And after that in your index.html file call this decorator in form tag like this

```
<form method="" action="">
{% csrf_token %}

.......

</form>
```

Comment: No. You should not give advice like this. CSRF protection is there for a reason; randomly disabling it is almost always the wrong thing to do.