# Django - CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-csrf

I just updated my django to 1.4. But I am getting the following error when I try to submit my login form:

> Forbidden (403)
>   CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
>   Reason given for failure:
>       CSRF token missing or incorrect.

In my settings.py (MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES) I had to remove the following line because its now deprecated:

```
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
```

And than I started to to get this error.

Some necessary information:
Urls.py

> ```
> url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'registration/login.html'}, name='login')
> ```

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
#   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
)
```

login.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} Login {% endblock %}
{% block content %}



   <div id="text">
        <table>
          <form action="" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
            <tr>
                <td><label for="username">Email:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="password">Password:</label></td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Login" />
            {% if next %}
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" /></td>
            {% else %}
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" /></td>
            {% endif %}
            </tr>
          </form>
        </table>


      {% if form.errors %}
        <p class="error">User or password incorrect</p>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code looks fine, Django 1.3 and 1.4 auth.views.login uses RequestContext correctly. Please check:

- Firstly clear data of browser and try again
- What's the value of submitted csrfmiddlewaretoken
- Do you import correct Django?
- Just make sure, is there UserWarning in console like?: "A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext."

Answer (score 3):

1. For 1.3 and 1.4, "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware" should be named "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware"
2. Also, for me clearing Google Chrome's cookies made it work.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue where my app was deployed on HTTPS. I had to change setting flag CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY to false so client server can access csrf cookie.

Answer (score 0):

**Clearing the Browser or Google Chrome cookies**, I hope it will work.