# CSRF_token is not valid in djnango Ajax multiple request from same page

Tags: python, jquery, django, django-templates, web-deployment

I'm trying to perform a OTP-based login in my project. So I have a form with email and password field in the login form and when I submit it through AJAX request I check for the email and password in the database, if the values are correct then I will send an OTP through email and display a new OTP field on the same page for Entering the OTP for verifications.

Till now everything is working fine but after entering the OTP when I try to re-submit the form, I got an error csrf_token is not valid. As far as I know csrf_token is only generated on page refresh or page load but in my case the first csrf_token that was generated on page load was used in first post request.

So now how can I send the second post request with same csrf_token or can I generate the new csrf_token.

Code snippets are as follows:

```
<form id="loginForm" method="post" action="send_otp">
  <div class="col-12">
    <label class="text-16 lh-1 fw-500 text-dark-1 mb-10">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Name">
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <label class="text-16 lh-1 fw-500 text-dark-1 mb-10">Password</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div id="otp_field" class="col-12">
                        
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="send_otp" class="button -md -green-1 text-dark-1 fw-500 w-1/1">Login</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Sending the request and adding the OTP input field on success through Ajax:

```
$("#loginForm").submit(function(event) {

  /* stop form from submitting normally */
  event.preventDefault();
  /* get the action attribute from the <form action=""> element */
  var $form = $(this),
    url = $form.attr('action');

  /* Send the data using post with element id name and name2*/
  var posting = $.post(url, {
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken":"{{ csrf_token }}",//$('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(),
    "email": $('#email').val(),
    "pass": $('#password').val()
  });

  /* Alerts the results */
  posting.done(function(data) {
    $('#email'). attr('disabled','disabled');
    $('#password'). attr('disabled','disabled');
    $('#otp_field').append('<label class="text-16 lh-1 fw-500 text-dark-1 mb-10">Enter OTP</label><input id="otp" type="text" name="otp" placeholder="Enter OTP">')
  });
  posting.fail(function() {
    
  });
});
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Add the javascript from this [django-doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/csrf/) to your page.

```
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

Pass `csrfmiddlewaretoken:getCookie('csrftoken')`

`{% csrf_token %}` returns an input tag, which you don't want, and have misspelled.

#### From another question:

Try adding the @csrf_protect decorator just before your login function.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

@csrf_protect
def login(request):
     csrfContext = RequestContext(request)
     return render_to_response('foo.html', csrfContext)
```

If the form is not in foo.html then you need to add the @csrf_protect method to the view function that is generating it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12731412/18020941

Comment: I have already tried to implement the same but still getting the same error message ```Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Forbidden (CSRF token from POST incorrect.): /verify_loginotp ```