# Django csrf_exempt not working with SessionAuthentication

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-csrf

I'm using Django Rest Framework to build a webapp with user registration/login. 
I'm trying to exempt the user sign up view from needing a CSRF token. This is what my view looks like right now:

```
class UserSignUpView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [] # FIXME: doesn't seem to be working
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return (permissions.AllowAny(), TokenHasReadWriteScope())
        return False
```

My settings.py looks like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
       'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ]
}
```

I still get this on my backend output `Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /users/` and in the front end the classic `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.`

Why wouldn't this work? Could it have something to do with the fact that I never manually set the CSRF cookie?

Comment: get_permissions don't need a decorator csrf_exempt? You are using POST method. You can write @csrf_exempt : [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_protect)

Comment: You can also see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716624/django-csrf-cookie-not-set)

Comment: @Wilfried I tried adding `@method_decorator(csrf_exempt)` to the top of `get_permissions` but no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django REST framework already prevents the `CSRFViewMiddleware` from performing a CSRF check by using `csrf_exempt` on any `APIView`. Instead, it explicitly calls the CSRF check when a user is successfully authenticated using `SessionAuthentication`. You can't bypass this check, nor should you. A regular Django view may not depend on the session, in which case a CSRF attack is not possible, and you can use `csrf_exempt` to indicate this. When you use `SessionAuthentication`, you **are** vulnerable to CSRF attacks, and you need the check to prevent attacks. Bypassing the check in this case invariably opens you up to a vulnerability, which is why DRF does not allow you to disable the check.

You basically have two options to fix this:

- Make sure the user it not successfully authenticated by `SessionAuthentication`.
- Ensure the cookie is set, and send the token in the `X-CsrfToken` request header.

Comment: I don't understand how SessionAuthentication is related to CSRF protection. I see that in Django you can't have the former without the latter, but I don't get why that's the case.

Comment: A CSRF attack is a way of abusing your session without your knowledge. If you don't have a session or similar mechanism, there's nothing an attacker can abuse by forging a cross-site request.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Makes perfect sense. So just to paraphrase, if authenticated with `SessionAuthentication`, `csrf_exempt` doesn't have any effect. In what scenario then would `csrf_exempt` actually be useful? According to what I've read, it's only when using `SessionAuthentification` that CSRF is checked, so using `csrf_exempt` otherwise is useless because CSRF isn't checked anyway.

Comment: Within Django REST framework? Never. However, Django doesn't implement the same `SessionAuthentication`, so it doesn't know which views are vulnerable, and it's up to you to determine which views should be protected. In that case you can use `csrf_exempt` on views that are not vulnerable.