# Django bug on CRSF token

Tags: django, django-csrf, django-cors-headers

I am using django as web API for backend and React JS as web UI for frontend. User will sign up from web UI which will send a POST request to django to register with the user details. I want to protect the signup view with CSRF. Therefore I come out with steps below.

First, once the sign up page is loaded, I fire a dummy `GET` request to store the csrf token with code below.

```
handleSend(){
  let req = {
    url: 'http://localhost:9000/vcubes/retrieve_token/',
    method : 'GET',
    withCredentials: true
  }
  axios(req)
}
```

Then, when user submit the signup form, another POST request will be fired.

```
const data = JSON.stringify({
        'first_name': this.state.first_name,
        'last_name': this.state.last_name,
        'email': this.state.email,
        'contact_number': this.state.contact_number,
        'password1': this.state.password1,
        'password2': this.state.password2,
      })
      let req = {
        url: 'http://localhost:9000/vcubes/signup/',
        method : 'POST',
        headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        },
        data: data
      }
      axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = this.getCookie('vcubes')
```

With the code above, an OPTIONS will be sent to django first and then after django send back a `200 OK`, then the actual POST request will be fired.

[image]
[image]

Surprise! Django stated that I do not set CSRF cookie.

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /vcubes/signup/
[30/Oct/2017 01:30:48] "POST /vcubes/signup/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2857
```

My `settings.py` is below. ( I only show some related code to CORS and CSRF)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'custom_user',
    'vcubes',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = (
    'localhost:8000',
    '127.0.0.1:8000'
)

CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'vcubes'

CSRF_HEADER_NAME = 'HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:8000',
    '127.0.0.1:8000'
)


CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'access-control-allow-credentials',
    'access-control-allow-origin',
    'access-control-request-method',
    'access-control-request-headers',
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'accept-language',
    'authorization',
    'connection',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'credentials',
    'host',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN',
    'X-CSRFToken',
    'x-requested-with',
)
```

In views.py

```
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def retrieve_token(request):
    return HttpResponse(status=200)

def signup(request):
    print request.META
    form = UserCreationForm(json.loads(request.body))
    # user = form.save(commit=False)
    # user.is_active = False
    # user.save()
    #
    # mail_subject = 'Activate your account.'
    # message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
    #     'name': user.get_full_name(),
    #     'domain': 'localhost:9000',
    #     'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
    #     'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
    # })
    # to_email = user
    # email = EmailMessage(
    #     mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
    # )
    # email.send()
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

I have been spending whole day to find out the problem from google and stackoverflow but hardly get any help. Please enlighten me!

Comment: is `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` set also ?

Comment: And if you didn't see this post, there are many fixes you could, try see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716624/django-csrf-cookie-not-set)

Comment: CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE is set false on default, which is fine for my case

Comment: Can you show the view for `/vcubes/retrieve_token/`? Also, `CSRF_header_NAME` should be all uppercase.

Comment: @knbk CSRF_HEADER_NAME also not working ( typo in process of debug haha) and already add in retrieve_token view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `withCredentials: true` for your post request, which means that your CSRF cookie is not sent with the request.

Comment: It works! Why I have to send withCredentials: true along with `axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = this.getCookie('vcubes')` ? Without the later code it still have `Cookie:vcubes=3HqESj1ea9Pw6gAah6CvlGOlvUDYURW1MBbwsXYpzIJWvXT6Sjiylpf2hDlSZgLh` in the request header.

Comment: The CSRF protection always requires that you send the token as a cookie. It also requires that you send the token in the request body, or as a header.