# CSRF verification failed error with react, axios and DRF

Tags: django, reactjs, rest, post, axios

I am trying to make a post request which looks like this

```
axios
        .post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create/${this.props.id}`, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Token ${token}`
          },
          xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN",
          xsrfHeaderName: "X-CSRFToken"
        })
        .then();
```

I have added essential things in settings.py also, such as 
`CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "XSRF-TOKEN"`

I also have

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',


    ),
}
```

Comment: I am getting 
Reason given for failure:

    CSRF cookie not set

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django bug on CRSF token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47003272/django-bug-on-crsf-token)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add `ensure_csrf_cookie` in your code.

A page makes a POST request via AJAX, and the page does not have an HTML form with a csrf_token that would cause the required CSRF cookie to be sent.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie
 @ensure_csrf_cookie
```

Read more about [ensure_csrf_cookie](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#page-uses-ajax-without-any-html-form). Let me know if that helps.