# How to pass CSRF token in POST data to Django?

Tags: django, fetch, csrf, django-csrf, js-cookie

I am developing an application with Django backend and Next.js frontend. I am trying to POST data from the frontend to the backend using the fetch API. **I am having problems passing a valid CSRF token in my POST data to Django.**

I am trying to do it by including an X-CSRFToken header in my POST request and getting its value using the [JavaScript Cookie Library](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/) recommended on Django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/#ajax).

Here is my fetch request:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

// POST data
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/dictionary/define', {     
  method: 'POST',     
  headers: {'X-CSRFToken': Cookies.get('csrftoken')},     
  body: JSON.stringify(data)})    
.then(response => response.json())   
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

The error I get from Django is of course one saying that the CSRF cookie was not set:

> Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /...

Can anybody tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: Did you take a look at this (for Django backend side)- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716624/django-csrf-cookie-not-set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by including credentials in my request:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

// POST data
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/dictionary/define', {     
  method: 'POST',
  credentials: 'include',     
  headers: {'X-CSRFToken': Cookies.get('csrftoken')},     
  body: JSON.stringify(data)})    
.then(response => response.json())   
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```