# CSRF cookie not set in Django POST

Tags: django, csrf

I have searched many of the SO questions and answers on this topic but cannot solve my problem. My js is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63940396/how-to-pass-csrf-token-in-post-data-to-django)

**xxx.js**

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

async function sendDataToAPI(uri, params) {
    let url = buildURI(uri, params);
    let endpoint = `${process.env.API_DOMAIN}${url}/`;
    try {
        const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
            method: "POST",
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': Cookies.get('csrftoken')},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                data: params,
            }),
        }
            );
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
    ...
```

**settings.py**

```
...

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:8888'
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:8888',
)
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
        "X-CSRFToken",
]
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...,
    'corsheaders',
...

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

I get ther error

> WARNING:django.security.csrf:Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)

Answer (score 0):

When this error occurs and `DEBUG` is enabled you should see this message on your browser:

> - Your browser is accepting cookies.
> - The view function passes a request to the template’s render method.
> - In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.
> - If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.
> - The form has a valid CSRF token. After logging in in another browser tab or hitting the back button after a login, you may need to reload the page with the form, because the token is rotated after a login.

In my case, all these requirements were correct - except I had `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True` and I was accessing the Django website through `http://` (not through `https://`).