# Django rest framework post requests gets Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to do some post requests to my Django project using DRF but it gives me this error :
`Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)` .. here is my code :

***serializers.py***

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','password','id']
```

**views.py**

```py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

**urls.py**

```py
router.register(r'main_users', UserViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django CSRF Cookie Not Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716624/django-csrf-cookie-not-set)

Comment: nop , nothing worked , i have searched everywhere before I post this question

Answer (score 0):

## add router.register in your urls.py may solve this question

i solved is after tried decotator @csrf_exempt and comment csrf in settings.py