# CSRF Failed | CSRF cookie not set

Tags: django, csrf-token

I'm using class based views to render a template. In that same class, I also have a post request to allow for the submission of a form.

However, when I submit the form, I get the CSRF cookie not set error. I did use the {% csrf_token %} but still doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
class SignIn(View):

  def get(self, request):
    # email = request.POST['email']
    # password = request.POST['password']
    template = loader.get_template('signin.html')
    logging.info(request)
    return HttpResponse(template.render())

  
  def post(self, request):
    email = request.POST['email']
    password1 = request.POST['password1']
    password2 = request.POST['password2']
    template = loader.get_template('signin.html')
    logging.info(request.__dict__)

    logging.info(password1)
    logging.info(email)

    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
      messages.info(request, 'E-mail Exists!')
      return redirect('signup')
    elif password1 != password2:
      messages.info(request, 'PASSWORD DOESNT MATCH')
      return redirect('signup')


    new_user = User.objects.create_user(email, email, password1)
    return HttpResponse(template.render())
```

This is my template:

```
<html>
  <div>
    <p>
      Signup
    </p>

    <form method = "POST" action="/signup">
      {% csrf_token %}
      username:
      <br/>
      <input type="text" name="email" />
      <br/>
      Password:
      <br/>
      <input type="password" name="password1" />
      <br/>
      confirm Password:
      <br/>
      <input type="password" name="password2" />
      <br/>
      <input class ="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value= "signup" />
      <br/>
    </form>
  </div>
</html>
```

My urls.py:

```
from django import views
from django.urls import path
from .views import SignUp, SignIn, Index

urlpatterns = [
  path('', Index.as_view(), name='Index'),
  path('signup', SignUp.as_view(), name='SignUp'),
  path('signin/', SignIn.as_view(), name='SignIn')
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django CSRF Cookie Not Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716624/django-csrf-cookie-not-set)

Comment: Not exactly. Could it be because I'm using a class-based view?