# Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.) : /accounts/register/ , django react

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, csrf-token

```js
import React, { useState } from "react"
import axios from "axios"
import CSRFToken from "./CSRFToken"

import Cookies from "js-cookie"

const Register = () => {

    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        email: "",
        username: "",
        password: "",
        re_password: ""

    })

    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': Cookies.get('csrftoken')
        }
    }


    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setFormData(() => ({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }))
    }

    const submitForm = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(formData)
        if (formData.password === formData.re_password) {
            if (formData.password.length < 8) {
                alert("Password should minimum of 8 characters")
            } else {
                console.log("Data is valid")
                try {
                    console.log(config)
                    const reg_req = await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/accounts/register/", JSON.stringify(formData), config)
                    console.log(reg_req.data)
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }

            }
        } else {
            alert("Passwords don't match")
        }
    }

    return <>
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-3"></div>
                <div className="col-md-6 border p-4 rounded mt-4">
                    <h2 className="my-2 mb-3">Register</h2>
                    <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
                        <CSRFToken />
                        <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input type="email" className="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="name@example.com" value={formData.email} onChange={handleChange} />
                            <label htmlFor="email">Email address</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username" value={formData.username} onChange={handleChange} />
                            <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input type="password" className="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value={formData.password} onChange={handleChange} />
                            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input type="password" className="form-control" id="re_password" name="re_password" placeholder="Re Password" value={formData.re_password} onChange={handleChange} />
                            <label htmlFor="re_password">Re Password</label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
}

export default Register
```

I am facing this error when I send post request, or when user try to register from react with django and django rest framework as backend

Comment: I think you can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716624/django-csrf-cookie-not-set