# Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): for django login from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django, axios

I am trying to access django server login from javascript

```
  axios.get('http://localhost:8010/get_csrf_token/').then((res)=>{
        console.log(res.data['csrf_token']);
        var data = {username:'admin@test.com',password:'testtest',
    
    }
    axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = res.data['csrf_token'];// set csrf_token in header.
    axios.post('http://localhost:8010/login/',data).then(() =>{
      console.log("test");
    })
  })
```

However this code shows the error below.

I set the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header but it requires cookie?

This django server is not third-party but under my controle, so I can change the setting of djang server.

How can I solve this?

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /login/
[WARNING][240326 200329] Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /login/
[26/Mar/2024 20:03:29] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2882
```

**update**

I checked if the cookie is set and set `withCredentials` true. but still has `Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)`

```
  axios.get('http://localhost:8010/get_csrf_token/').then((res)=>{
    document.cookie = `csrftoken=${res.data['csrf_token']}`;
    console.log("cookie:",document.cookie); // to confirm cookie is set here.
    var data = {username:'admin@test.com',password:'testtest'}
    axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = res.data['csrf_token'];
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
    axios.post('http://localhost:8010/login/',data,{
      withCredentials: true,
    }).then(() =>{
      console.log("test");
    })
  })
```

Comment: Hi, did you already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716624/django-csrf-cookie-not-set)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I set `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False` or `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True`, but problem not solved.

Comment: Would it not make more sense, if `http://localhost:8010/get_csrf_token/` actually _set_ a cookie (instead of returning the token in a JSON response, as it appears to be the case now) - and then you use `withCredentials: true` in your axios request options, to make it receive and send cross-origin cookies? https://stackoverflow.com/q/43002444/1427878

Comment: Thank you `CBroe` I updated the article, check cookie is correctly set and set `withCredentials:true` however same error.

Comment: If you have the default setting for `CSRF_HEADER_NAME` then `X-CSRF-TOKEN` is wrong and instead should be `X-CSRFTOKEN` (Note the lack of a hyphen between CSRF and TOKEN)

Comment: Thank you @Abdul  , I changed X-CSRF-TOKEN  to X-CSRFTOKEN but same error