# Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Even using the {% csrf_token %}

Tags: python, django, authentication, csrf, django-csrf

i am trying to do a login in django but i get this error, i check the CSRF documentation and nothing works for me.

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
  <section class="container">
    <div class="login">
      <h1>Login to Web App</h1>

      {% if form.errors %}
        <p class="error">Lo sentimos, la combinacion de usuario y contrasena no es correcta!</p>
      {% endif %}  

      <form action="/accounts/auth/" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}  
      <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='randomchars'/>

        <p><input name="username" type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username"></p>

        <p><input name="password" type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>

        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
      </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Like you see above i use the {% csrf_token %} and i have 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' in my installed apps.

And my views are:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template.loader import get_template 
from django.template import Context
from datetime import datetime
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import auth
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

from models import *
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from forms import *
from django.template.context import RequestContext
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def login(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('login.html', c)    


def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request.user)
        return HttpResponse('/accounts/loggedin') 
    else:
        return HttpResponse('/accounts/invalid')
```

i redirect to an other HTML file where i dont use the {% csrf_token %}.

Comment: I was suffered this error, even though using {% csrf_token %}. But after changing **render_to_response** to just **render**, It was solved.

Answer (score 29):

## Theory

---

A couple of things are required to make the csrf protection work (check out the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/)):

1. Your browser has to accept cookies from your server
2. Make sure you have '`django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` included as middleware in your `settings.py` (alternatively use the decorator csrf_protect() on particular views you want to protect)
3. Make sure you pass on the csrf token from `django.core.context_processors.csrf` to the context manager.

When you load your page, have a look in the page source using your favorite browser. Don't open the template html file, open the url which point to the view containing the form. Look at where you placed the `{% csrf_token %}`. If you see something like

```
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value="jdwjwjefjwdjqwølksqøwkop2j3ofje" />
```

you should be ok.

If you on the other hand see `NOTPROVIDED`, something has gone wrong while creating the csrf token. By looking in the source code (`context_processors.py` and `csrf.py`), we can find out what:

- `csrf(request)` returns `{'csrf_token': 'NOTPROVIDED'}` if `get_token(request)` returns None.
- `get_token(request)` returns `request.META.get("CSRF_COOKIE", None)`.

I assume this means that it would return `None` if the cookie isn't successfully created.

## Fix

---

For you, this means that you should first replace

```
<form action="/accounts/auth/" method="post" {% csrf_token %}>
```

with

```
<form action="/accounts/auth/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
(...)
</form>
```

We'd like the csrf field to be inside `<form>...</form>`, not *inside* `<form>`. As the code is at the moment, it will be converted to

```
<form action="/accounts/auth/" method="post" <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='randomchars' />>
```

and we would rather like

```
<form action="/accounts/auth/" method="post">
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='randomchars' />
```

After that - have a look at the source code, and see if you can find the csrf field. If you can see it, everything should work in theory.

You can also check that the csrf cookie has been set in your browser, e.g. in Chrome, right-click the web page, and select `Insepect Element`. Select the `Resources` tab, and click on cookies. You should find a cookie name `csrftoken` there.

If you still have problems, double-check the middleware tuple in your `settings.py` and double-check that your browser accept cookier from your server as described above.

Comment: I did it, but still get nothing, same error comes out. Use the @csrf_exempt in my views but nothing still happen

Comment: Ok, but the HTML posted is from the /accounts/login/ URL , so when i click in submit(login) button it redirect me to /accounts/auth/ URL, that call the auth_view method in my views. i dont have a HTML file for the /accounts/auth/ URL. Maybe thats the problem... What you think?

Comment: @BismarthSantana I want the html you get when you are on the page with the submit button, and click View -> Source in your favourite browser.

Comment: @BismarthSantana I made a substansial edit to my answer - please have a look.

Comment: Great help! Did everything you told me, Still have the error... I have updated my code with all i have done and you can see it above. Also my browser is permitting cookies.

Comment: @BismarthSantana You need to paste the html which is _produced_ by the template, not the template itself. This means that you should go to the url which points to the login-view and copy the source from that page. The template engine should transform the {% csrf_token %} into either `NOTPROVIDED` or a input field.

Comment: Does anyone reading this have any insights into why this error would occur seemingly randomly? Users sometimes get this error when trying to save a form, yet I can open a copy of the form in a new tab in the same browser on the same computer, copy and paste their data into the second tab and save that just fine. I have RequestContext in my view, have django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware in settings, and the form that generates the error has replaced {% csrf_token %} with
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="KLJtq68rqZGLZt0J5cDO8qsIYKo7Sm3g">
inside <form></form>.

Comment: I have no idea @jen - try asking a new question with as much context as possible.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806375/django-csrf-failure-after-upgrade-1-9-1-11

Answer (score 4):

Clear your browser cache and try again. Maybe it is using the CSRF token saved in cached cookie.

Comment: This worked for me. I was getting that error even on pages that had no forms

Comment: Just refreshing the page and refilling out the form worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

With Addition of above answer, Try Adding following lines in the views

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
def somathing():
   return something
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't make the security work, rather it removes this security mechanism.

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Simple and easy. +1.