# How to handle simple form submission in python django?

Tags: django

Hello I am trying to handle simple form submission in django. But still after hours of try. I am getting csrf verification failed error. I searched a lot but no solution is found so far.

This is my code

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        useremail = request.POST.get('useremail')
    context = {
        'username': username,
        'useremail': useremail
    }

    template = loader.get_template('responsepage.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
else:
    template = loader.get_template('formpage.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render())
```

It is my form

```
<form method="post" action="/getdata/">
    {{% csrf_token %}}
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="email" name="useremail" />
</form>
```

I have written csrf_token variable here. But still I am getting the same error that csrf verification failed.

Comment: you are probably missing {% csrf_token %} in your template (which you have not posted)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Even using the {% csrf\_token %}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895526/forbidden-403-csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted-even-using-the-csr)

Comment: You tried and searched for _hours_? I find that difficult to believe. There are lots and lots of results for how to make CSRF verification work in Django. Marking your question as possible duplicate of one of them until you give us more information on where yours is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put this after your form tag in your view

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

And while rendering the output use

```
return render(request, 'responsepage.html', context)
```

Django gives this security feature to prevent cross site request forgery. If you don't want to use this feature of security you can temporarily disable it by putting

```
@csrf_exempt
```

Source: [Django Forms Tutorial](https://www.simplifiedpython.net/django-forms-tutorial-working-forms/)

Comment: Though it is working after putting this annotation. But i want to use csrf

Answer (score 2):

If you use the csrf token on the `formpage.html` template, then you need to render the template with the `request` object.

```
template = loader.get_template('formpage.html')
return HttpResponse(template.render(request=request))
```

You might want to simplify the code by using the `render` shortcut instead:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        return render(request, 'responsepage.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'formpage.html')
```