# Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Django

Tags: python, django

I have this error when loading the template the model of the form, and enter the amount in the The text sends me to the page Help
Reason given for failure:
The CSRF symbol is missing or incorrect. From Django, help pls!

views.py:

```
def ListAll(request, id_especialidad):
especialidad = Especialidad.objects.get(id=id_especialidad)
if request.method == 'GET':
  user = request.user
  if user.is_superuser:
      pedido = Pedido.objects.filter(especialidad=especialidad)
      template  = 'admindata.html'
      return render_to_response(template,locals())
  else:
    if request.method == 'POST':
      form = PedidoEditForm(instance=especialidad)
    else:
      form = PedidoEditForm(request.POST, instance=especialidad)
      if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          pedido = Pedido.objects.filter(especialidad=especialidad)
  return render_to_response('index2.html',locals(), {'form':form})
```

template html:

```
   {% if especialidad.estadistica == "0" %}
   <section id="contenido">
  <div class="container" style="margin:50px auto width="100%"">
     <form id="myform" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;
        <input type="submit" class= "btn btn-success" value="Guardar">
     {% else %}
     <table id="example" class="table table-border table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr> 
                <td>Servicio</td>
                <td>Cod experto</td>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>Cantidad</td>
                <td>Ingresar</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>Servicio</td>
                <td>Cod experto</td>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>Cantidad</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
    {% if pedido  %}
    {% for ped in pedido  %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ ped.especialidad.nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ ped.articulo.cod_experto }}</td>
                <td>{{ ped.articulo.nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ ped.cantidad }}</td>
                <td><a href="{% url "usuario:cant_ingresar" ped.id especialidad.id  %}" method='GET' type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="editar" onclick="document.location.reload();"/>Ingresar</a></td>

            </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
       </tbody>
       </table>
       </form>

</div>
</section>
</div>
```

{% endif %}

model form:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Pedido, Especialidad


class PedidoEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cantidad       = forms.IntegerField(label='Cantidad:',     widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'10'}))

class Meta:
    model = Pedido


    fields = [

    'cantidad',

    ]  

class EstadisticaForm(forms.ModelForm):
estadistica    = forms.IntegerField(label='Estadistica Menusal:', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Ingrese numero pacientes'}))  

class Meta:
    model = Especialidad

    fields = [

    'estadistica',

    ]
```

In this use the second: EstadisticaForm.
What is the estimated problem? 
regards!

Comment: Am I missing something or your `form` actually never renders in full? The `else` of `{% if especialidad.estadistica == "0" %}` is called before well before the `</form>`

Comment: Yes sir, the idea is that if the statistic is 0, it sends me to the model forms, and otherwise (else) I list the table that is in the form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Even using the {% csrf\_token %}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895526/forbidden-403-csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted-even-using-the-csr)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to debug this because the indentation of the code for `views.py` is messed up but it looks like you have an issue there. In my form handling views I usually set an `if` test to handle the `POST` case and then put the logic for the `GET` in the else branch. Cleaning up your view should help reveal the problem (because it looks like you have two cases in the `POST` case and that doesn't make sense to me). I'd also suggest you switch from `render_to_response` to `render` and get out of the habit of passing `locals()`, instead explicitly passing the things you need in the context. Also, it looks like you have messed up the signature of [`render_to_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) as you are passing `locals()` in for your context but then passing the form explicitly. I think you've conflated two different examples of view rendering you've seen. I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to do but I think this approach is cleaner:

```
def ListAll(request, id_especialidad):
    template = 'index2.html'
    especialidad = Especialidad.objects.get(id=id_especialidad)
    pedido = Pedido.objects.filter(especialidad=especialidad)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PedidoEditForm(request.POST, instance=especialidad)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # return a redirect here on success
    # handles GET case and when form fails
    user = request.user
    if user.is_superuser:
        template = 'admindata.html'

    return render(request, template, {'form':form, 'pedido': pedido, 'especialidad': especialidad})
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you've placed the `if`, `else` and `endif` you will never render a complete form. I'm not sure this is the cause of your problem, but certainly is a problem.

Try with this example:

```
<section id="contenido">
    <div class="container" style="margin:50px auto width="100%"">
        {% if especialidad.estadistica == "0" %}
        <form id="myform" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            <input type="submit" class= "btn btn-success" value="Guardar">
        </form>
        {% else %}
        <table id="example" class="table table-border table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr> 
                    <td>Servicio</td>
                    <td>Cod experto</td>
                    <td>Nombre</td>
                    <td>Cantidad</td>
                    <td>Ingresar</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td>Servicio</td>
                    <td>Cod experto</td>
                    <td>Nombre</td>
                    <td>Cantidad</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                {% if pedido  %}
                {% for ped in pedido  %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ ped.especialidad.nombre }}</td>
                    <td>{{ ped.articulo.cod_experto }}</td>
                    <td>{{ ped.articulo.nombre }}</td>
                    <td>{{ ped.cantidad }}</td>
                    <td><a href="{% url "usuario:cant_ingresar" ped.id especialidad.id  %}" method='GET' type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="editar" onclick="document.location.reload();"/>Ingresar</a></td>

                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a broken form by the first {% if %}. If it's false, you don't have the code to open the form tag.

```
   {% if especialidad.estadistica == "0" %}
   <section id="contenido">
    <div class="container" style="margin:50px auto width="100%"">
     <form id="myform" method="POST"><!-- IF FALSE, NEVER RENDERS -->
    {% csrf_token %}
        ...
     {% else %}<!-- RENDER THE BEGGINING OF THE FORM AGAIN -->
     <form id="myform" method="POST"> 
    {% csrf_token %}
     </form>
```

Comment: And also the rest of the tags, your first {% if %} is not sourrinding the html tags properly.