# CSRF verification failed after adding a filefield on model

Tags: django, aws-serverless

I'm having a weird problem.
So I have an application where my model was completely fine until I added a Filefield to it.

Now I'm getting a CSRF-Verification failed error, even if I don't try to upload a file and leave it blank, it gives me the error below.

[image]

This is my model:

```
class Municipality(models.Model):
    activate_date = models.DateField()
    deactivate_date = models.DateField()
    code = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    alt_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    logo = models.FileField( upload_to='Logo/muni', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

My Application is set up on AWS using AWS Lambda, S3, and other needed services

My S3 bucket (where my file should be uploaded to) is defined in my `settings.py` file with the env variable that has been defined on AWS Lambda environment variables

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = env('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME', default=None)
```

I don't get why my model won't save even if I don't include a file.

The weird thing about it is that when I'm working locally, it doesn't give me this error.
And I can save this model with or without uploading a file.

Other models where no Filefield or Imagefield is defined are perfectly working online and locally.

Any reasons why I'm getting this error whenever I try to add a Filefield or Imagefield?

**NOTE:** I'm working in the DjangoAdmin interface and not custom forms, so I think django automatically adds the csrf token if I'm right?

**EDIT:** I noticed that my csrf token in my request headers cookie is different than in the payload of the request, is this normal?

**EDIT:** I updated my django project to v4.0,now the error onnly says `CSRF token missing`

**EDIT:** I found out that when I save a model in the admin that has a image/filefield in it, my POST data is not sent with my request. So it makes sence that I get an error, CSRF token missing.

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I've been bugging out to Chrome just to upload things for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

When using a `models.FileField` in Django, the key point is to declare the `enctype` as following:

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
  ...
  {% csrf_token %}
  ...
</form>
```

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/).

Comment: mb, I should have said that I'm working with the DjangoAdmin interface. Not custom forms. So I think DjangoAdmin does this automatically?

Comment: I don't know, you can check the html source in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try clearing cookies and refreshing
2. Check to make sure you have
   **django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware** in your **middleware**
3. Check that you're either on https or you have
   **CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE=False**

Comment: Thanks for the response, sadly I tried all those things without success

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check by undoing the changes you made to the model. If the problem still persists ,then you may have made some change elsewhere. Also try it from a different device and user account(even after clearing cookies/hard reload, somethimes browsers behave unexpectedly).
You can also try answers from these links.([link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573163/django-admin-login-suddenly-demanding-csrf-token), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895526/forbidden-403-csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted-even-using-the-csr) )

Checking the html source may help.
Also, if you are using custom django admin forms, check them again if they require any changes. Using `@csrf_exempt` while trying different scenarios may help you understand, if this error is really because of csrf or there is another problem.

Also see this in django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS).

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. Played with requires_csrf_token and csrf_protect. None worked for me.
Browser was launched in user session, and uploading file was 777 root:root in /home/username. changed file owner to user, and all worked.

So, in some scenarios, not only chmod 777, but chown username:username.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue. My problem was with the file permissions, I had to use `sudo chmod 777 file`