# CSRF token missing or incorrect in django

Tags: python, django

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse
import MySQLdb
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context, Template,RequestContext
import datetime
import hashlib
from random import randint
import random
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect, csrf_exempt
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
import requests
from django.template import RequestContext
from log.forms import *

@csrf_protect
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
            password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
            email=form.cleaned_data['email']
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success/')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
    'form': form
    })

    return render_to_response(
    'register.html',
    variables,
    )
   # return render(request,"recharge.html")
def register_success(request):
    return render_to_response(
    'registration/success.html',
    )
```

> ```
> base.html
> ```

```
 <form method="post" action="."> {% csrf_token %}
        <table border="0"> 
                { form.as_table }}
        </table>
    <button type="submit" value="Register">Register</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='/' ">Login</button>
 </form>
```

> register.html

```
<!-- register.html -->
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}User Registration{% endblock %}
{% block head %}User Registration{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
        <table border="0">
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        <button type="submit" value="Register">Register</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='/' ">Login</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

> settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**My django version: 1.10.4**

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: can y send inspect or rendered HTML ?

Comment: rendered HTML means do you want register html?

Comment: yes please .. so we can help u on it

Comment: i don't need html coded , i need inspect from html page from web browser

Comment: i check it please remove @csrf_protect from the view

Comment: also if u can send us settings.py to check it

Comment: this is my MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

Comment: removed @csrf_protect in the view. still it doesn't work

Comment: django.core.context_processors.csrf add this in context processor of for template in settings.py

Comment: @VenkateshPanabaka please see my answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSRF Token missing or incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089224/csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect)

Comment: send us your template processors

Comment: @VenkateshPanabaka can you update your base.html the base.html that you gave seems to be broken. can you paste your exact base.html?

Comment: my base.html is too big because of that i pasted small code

Comment: if you use RequestContext check if you have django.core.context_processors.csrf in your CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.

Comment: Thank u for all. My problem is solved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

call `render_to_response` like this:

```
from django.template import RequestContext

@csrf_protect
def register(request):
    # ...

    return render_to_response(
        'register.html',
        {'form': form}, 
        RequestContext(request)
    )
```

or **just use render shortcut method**

```
@csrf_protect
def register(request):
    # ...
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

from [1.8 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render):

> render() is the same as a call to render_to_response() with a context_instance argument that forces the use of a RequestContext.

Comment: we can remove csrf_protect as Django by default verifies csrf_token for post requests.

Comment: have you tried using the `render` method, not `render_to_response`? part 2 of my answer?