# I am new to django. How to resolve the csrf token missing or incorrect error? I have used render request in views

Tags: django, csrf

403 forbidden. CSRF token missing or incorrect.
I have already tried from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect, it doesn't work. I have not used render_to_request either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSRF Token missing or incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089224/csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect)

Comment: Tried those. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of the csrf_token in the html of the form. That's a requirement. Do a search on `csrf_token` to read about it and/or [read the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/).

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/finance/gl_upload/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{form.as_table}}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="Save" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Good to know. You might want to add some more information to your question, then. If you've tried things, then you should show that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried clearing the data and it worked! Thank you all for the help.