# Not sure why im getting a (CSRF token missing or incorrect.) error in django

Tags: python-3.x, django

HTML:

```
{% extends 'generic.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
<title>Projects - Login</title>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<form action='#', method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    <input type='submit' value='Login!'>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
def login(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.login, name='login')
]
```

I have tried putting a @csrf_protect decorator on the login function. however I still get the same error.

Comment: provide full error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSRF Token missing or incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089224/csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect)

Answer (score 0):

Change the form in your template:

```html
<form action="{% url 'your_app_name:login' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
...
</form>
```

or,

```html
<form action="login/" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
...
</form>
```