# Example of when to use render_to_response over render

Tags: django

From the documentation:

**render**

> Combines a given template with a given context dictionary and returns an HttpResponse object  with that rendered text.
>
> render() is the same as a call to render_to_response() with a context_instance argument that forces the use of a RequestContext.

**render_to_response**

> Renders a given template with a given context dictionary and returns an HttpResponse object with that rendered text.

Can you provide a task-oriented example and a description of when one would choose to use `render_to_response` in a view versus `render`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154358/django-what-is-the-difference-between-render-render-to-response-and-direc

Answer (score -1):

Well the only difference is that with render_to_response you could pass in a different context dictionary to view (template). By default RequestContext will build up a "context" via the Django's middleware functions defined in your settings file TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.

Comment: You can (and should) pass it a context to `render` as well. The difference is that it creates a RequestContext.