# User is not being passed to template TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS

Tags: django

Following the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth)

> If TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS contains this processor, **every**
>   RequestContext will contain these variables:
>
> user – An auth.User instance representing the currently logged-in user
>   (or an AnonymousUser instance, if the client isn’t logged in). perms –
>   An instance of django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper,
>   representing the permissions that the currently logged-in user has.

I added these lines to `settings.py`

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
)
```

Rendering my templates as follows

```
def profile_view(request):
    return render_to_response('profile.html', { 'profile' : 1 })
```

I was under the impression that the request context along with the user will be passed automatically. Is that not the case, or should i explicitly add `context_instance=template.RequestContext(request))` to every view ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you want to use `render_to_response` and you want template context data available, you should pass in a `RequestContext` instance.

Alternatively, if you render your page with [`django.shortcuts.render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/shortcuts/#render), the `RequestContext` will be injected automatically.

You may find this answer useful, too: [Django - what is the difference between render(), render_to_response() and direct_to_template()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154358/)