# Passing variables to templates in Django

Tags: python, html, django, templates

I have seen similar questions and answers but none that address my problem.

I want my view to perform a User Group check and then pass that via variable to the template. The template will then use that to appear differently to different user groups.

My views.py:

```
def cans(request):
    is_canner = request.user.groups.filter(name='canner') #check if user group = canner
    can_list = Can.objects.order_by('name')
    context = {'can_list': can_list}
    return render(request, 'cans/cans.html', context) #need to return is_canner variable here
```

And in my template I would use the variable like so:

```
{% if is_canner %} canner stuff goes here {% endif %}
```

I'm unsure how to pass this variable, I thought it used context to send it like so:

```
return render(request, 'cans/cans.html', context({"is_canner": is_canner}))
```

But this gives me errors - context is not callable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

context is not a function, its an argument to the render function, e.g.

```
context = {"is_canner": is_canner}
return render(request, 'cans/cans.html', context)
```

docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

more background info: [Django - what is the difference between render(), render_to_response() and direct_to_template()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154358/django-what-is-the-difference-between-render-render-to-response-and-direc)

Comment: This gives me an error when loading the template: render_to_string() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'