# pass data from Django view to react

Tags: django, reactjs

I have a django view that returns a variable in order to be rendered in template

```
return render_to_response('index.html', {
    'courses': courses})
```

I'm using ReactJS to render the index.html file, but I'm not sure whether i have to point to index.html in my view or the ReactJS file.
If I have to point to index.html how can I use the courses variable with React ?

**Update**
the variable courses that i'm passing is of type dictionnary

Comment: sorry for not mentioning that, courses is a dictionnary

Answer (score 1):

Templates processing is anterior to any sort of JavaScript interpretation. This means that you will have to, in some sense, emulate its hardcoding beetween the js tags.

First, know that the python dictionary is likely to be corrupted when received on the client side. To prevent this, you may want to send it as a json object. Which means that, in you script views.py, you will have to `json.dumps` your dictionary. As follows

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import json
#...
    #...
    return render(request,
                 'your_app/index.html',\
                  {'courses': json.dumps(courses)}\
                  )
```

Note that I use `render` instead of `render_to_response`, because `render` [is a brand spanking new shortcut for render_to_response in 1.3 that will automatically use RequestContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154358/django-what-is-the-difference-between-render-render-to-response-and-direc)

Also, note that you do have to point to your index.html, but the exact path depends on the strucutre of your project. Above, I assume you followed the recommended django project layout, i.e.

```
myproject/
    manage.py
    your_project/
        __init__.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
        settings/
            __init__.py
            base.py
            dev.py
            prod.py
    your_app/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        managers.py
        views.py
        urls.py
        templates/
            your_app/
                index.html
    [...]
```

Then, on the html side,

```
...
<script>
 var courses = {{courses|safe}}
// working with the variable courses
</script>
...
```

Now, you can do what you want with it, be it with [ReactJS](https://github.com/reactjs) library.

Comment: I followed your answer and i tried to iterate over the courses variable but It gave an error that it's not iterable. However I have another doubt because i think i have to fetch the variable inside the react file wich is a seperate one from the index.html file

Comment: @ChemseddineZ. Not iterable ? In JavaScript ? How did you do that ? Like this : 

`for (var prop in courses) {
        alert("Key:" + prop);
        alert("Value:" + courses[prop]);
}` ?